# multiple breaklines symbols for minted

Tags: line-breaking, minted

I would like to allow minted to break lines after either `.`, `,` or a space.
Currently I could only break lines either after `,` or before `.`
How can I allow more characters?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{upquote}
\setminted{fontsize=\small, breaklines=true, breakbefore=., breakafter={,}, 
breakbytokenanywhere=true, frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=5pt, fontfamily=tt}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
results = pd.DataFrame(data=results,columns=['Clusters C','Intertia']).set_index('Clusters')
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `breakafter={<char 1><char 2>...}`, and use `\space` to represent  , as mentioned under option `breakafter` in [documentation of package `fvextra`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fvextra/fvextra.pdf). Note that `breakafter` option is defined in `fvextra` and inherited by `minted`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{upquote}
\setminted{
  fontsize=\small, 
  breaklines=true, 
  breakafter={.,\space}, 
  breakbytokenanywhere=true, 
  frame=single, 
  numbers=left, 
  numbersep=5pt, 
  highlightcolor={red!20}, 
  fontfamily=tt
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
# break after .
results = pd.DataFrame(data=results,columns=['Clusters C','Intertia']).set_index('Clusters')
# break after ,
results = pd.DataFrame(data=results,columns=['Clusters C','Intertia','Extra col']).set_index('Clusters')
# break after \space
result_a result_b result_c result_d result_e result_f result_g result_h result_i = some_tuple
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]